# ¿Que configuración requiero para visualizar PDF en mi aplicación web hecha con Django?

Tags: django, pdf

He intentado visualizar archivos pdf en mi página web pero Django me da dice que "Localhost rechazó la conexión", el programa guarda, modifica y elimina los archivos PDF, solo es la visualización la que falla. Todo esto lo estoy haciendo usando la base de datos MySQL.

> Este es mi archivo urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static

#Aquí colocamos nuestras URLs

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.inicio, name='inicio'),
    path('personal', views.personal, name='personal'),
    path('personal/crear', views.crear_empleado, name='crear_empleado'),
    path('personal/editar', views.edit_empleado, name='edit_empleado'),
    path('eliminar/<int:id>', views.eliminar_empleado, name='eliminar_empleado'),
    path('personal/editar/<int:id>', views.edit_empleado, name='edit_empleado'),
    
]
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root 
=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> Este es mi archivo views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Personal
from .forms import PersonalForm

# Create your views here.
def inicio(request):
    return render(request, 'paginas/inicio.html')

def personal(request):
    personal = Personal.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'personal/index.html', {'personal': personal})
```

> Este es mi template que debe de visualizar el pdf, recalco que si encuentra los archivos pero me rechaza la conexión solo en la columna de los PDF

```html
<tbody>
                {% for ingeniero in personal %}
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">{{ ingeniero.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ingeniero.carrera }}</td>
                    <td>{{ ingeniero.experiencia }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <embed src="{{ ingeniero.cv.url }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
                    </td>

                    <!--td>
                        <embed src="{{ ingeniero.cv.url }}" height="100"></embed>                        
                    </td-->
                    <td><a name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'edit_empleado' ingeniero.id %}" role="button">Modificar</a> 
                        | 
                        <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'eliminar_empleado' ingeniero.id %}" role="button">Eliminar</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
```

> Este es mi archivo settings.py

```html
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-dv#ouay$0l^&gu&fisq@=0(&02$-0#uuz#1165drvi2_cj@dsl'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'empleados',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'rh_pdm',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '')
MEDIA_URL = '/cvs/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

> Este es mi archivo models.py

```html
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Personal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombre')
    carrera = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Carrera', null=True)
    experiencia = models.CharField(max_length=600, verbose_name='Experiencia', null=True)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cvs/', verbose_name="CVS", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        fila = "Nombre: " + self.nombre + " - " + "Carrera: " + self.carrera + " - " + "Experiencia: " + self.experiencia
        return fila
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estructura del proyecto

```
/core
/media/cvs
/personal
 db.sqlite3
 manage.py
```

settings.py

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN' #Antes de los MIDDLEWARE

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

core/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include('personal.urls')),
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

personal/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from personal import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.personal, name="home"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

intente con esta configuracion:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.inicio, name='inicio'),
path('personal', views.personal, name='personal'),
path('personal/crear', views.crear_empleado, name='crear_empleado'),
path('personal/editar', views.edit_empleado, name='edit_empleado'),
path('eliminar/<int:id>', views.eliminar_empleado, name='eliminar_empleado'),
path('personal/editar/<int:id>', views.edit_empleado, name='edit_empleado'),
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Recuerde tener creada la carpeta media y la las direcciones en el archivos settings

settigs.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Amigo, no me resolvió el problema. Me arroja el error de "Localhost rechazó la conexión" pero solo es en la parte del PDF, ya no se que hacer.

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta con los views, forms, y también los templates si los tienes

Comment: Listo amigo, ya no tengo el error 404 pero ahora me sale en la parte del <embed> que Localhost rechazó la conexión.

Comment: En este caso puede ser la configuración de los host así que deja la configuración por defecto de django, este caso seria : ALLOWED_HOSTS = [], si persiste el error actualice la pregunta con la estructura del proyecto y los modelos

Comment: Esa parte no la toqué amigo, pero ya he actualizado la respuesta, agregué el settings.py y models.py

Comment: En media root tienes que poner la carpeta donde se guardan los arcvhiso que estas subiendo en este: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cvs'), si esto no funciona agregue X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN' antes de los MIDDLEWARE

Comment: Ya he agregado el código y sigue el mismo error

Comment: Lo peor de todo es que no veo respuesta concreta de este problema en ningún lado, es como si nadie visualizara PDF's en aplicaciones web hechas en Django jajaja

Comment: Creo que el error lo tienes en los urls, acabo de hacer un proyecto con tus mismos modelos para probar lo de la visualizacion de pdf por mi mismo y me ha funcionado asi que ya subo la estructura del proyecto para que lo compares con el tuyo

Comment: algo mas a comentar es que estas poniendo + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) en las urls de la app y estas deben ir en las urls del core, así que por favor elimine esto de las urls de la app e ingréselo en urls de core

Comment: Ya lo eliminé de la url de la app y solo lo dejé en Core y sigue igual. Estaré atento a tu proyecto, gracias.

Comment: acabo de crear una nueva respuesta con la estructura y las configuraciones que use, si sigues sin resolver el problema házmelo saber y subiré el proyecto a github para que pueda revisarlo con mas comodidad

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138103/discussion-between-jose-andres-ramos-alvarez-and-json).